# How to expand $\frac{1}{(1+z^2)}$ in powers of $(z-a)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How to expand $\frac{1}{(1+z^2)}$ in powers of $(z-a)$?

I know for people who knows how to do this this is a stupid problem. But I am just a beginner. Differentiating $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$ seems not a sensable way. I also try to do this problem from the taylor series at $0$ but failed because I cannot see a clear pattern.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: To expand a rational function of $z$ into a power series in $z-a$, write the function as a rational function in $w:=z-a$ first, compute the Taylor series at $w=0$, then substitute back as $w:=z-a$.

Comment: @seaturtles The Taylor series of 1/(1+z^2) is pretty easy.But the question is when I substitute back I can not find obvious pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the binomial theorem,

$$(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n$$

Letting $x=z^2$,

$$(1+z^2)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^{2n}$$

This gives the series expansion around $z=0$. To expand around $z=a$, you can try this:

As Mayank Pandey pointed out,

$$\frac{1}{z^2 + 1}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}\right)$$

For the first term,

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
\frac{1}{z+i}&=&\frac{1}{(a+i)+(z-a)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{a+i}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-a}{a+i}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{a+i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{z-a}{a+i}\right)^n
\end{array}$$

Do the same to the second term and combine like terms in the series.

Comment: Didn't you miss a $-1$ in your 3th equation?

Comment: Your third line should be $\dfrac{1}{2i}\left(\dfrac{1}{z-i}- \dfrac{1}{z+i}\right)$. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{z^2 + 1} = \frac{1/2i}{z - i} - \frac{1/2i}{z + i}$$ In general, you can do this to any poynomial.

Comment: It looks promising.So what I need to do is just expand 1/(z+i) and 1/(z-1),right?

Comment: See the newer answer by solstafir.