# How to expand $\frac{1}{1-z}$ about $z=i$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a problem for my introductory course in complex analysis, to expand $\frac{1}{1-z}$ about $z=i$. I think this means putting $$\frac{1}{1-(w+i)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(w+i)^n$$ in terms of $w=z-i$, but I don't know how to do that. I've read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757102/how-to-expand-frac11z2-in-powers-of-z-a) question and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792634/how-to-expand-frac12z-z2-about-z-1) one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac 1 {1-(i+w)}=\frac 1 {1-i}\cdot \frac 1 {1-\frac w {1-i}}=\frac 1 {1-i}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac w {1-i}\right)^n$$

Comment: Could you explain the first equality a bit, e.g. with additional steps?

Comment: $\frac 1 {1-i}\cdot \frac 1 {1-\frac w {1-i}}=\frac 1 {(1-i)(1-\frac w {1-i})}=\frac 1 {1-i-w}=\frac 1 {1-(i+w)}$